# httperrors in system.webserver not working on azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

I would like to catch all errors into a default.aspx file, no matter what happens on the server.

In the web.config, I added:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" defaultPath="~/Default.aspx" existingResponse="Replace" >
        <remove statusCode="404"/>
        <remove statusCode="500"/>
        <error statusCode="404" path="~/Default.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
        <error statusCode="500" path="~/Default.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

It does not work. In an question, I read about allow overriding of the HttpErrors section, but adding something in the configSection does not work, since the type element is missing. No idea what is required there.

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ZZZZZZZZZ" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="httpErrors" allowOverride="true"/>
</configSections>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to handle 404 error messages in ASP.NEt Website, then all you need is to have following section in Web.Config -

```
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="DefaultRedirectErrorPage">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Home/About"/>
    </customErrors>
```

For detailed understanding of different ways of error handling in ASP.Net - [Ref this MSDN Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.aspx)

If you wanted to do that at httpErrors level, then try this -

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
     <!--Remove inherited 500 error page setting -->
     <remove statusCode='404' subStatusCode='-1'/> 
     <!--Override the inherited 500 error page setting with the 'My500.html' as its path-->
     <error statusCode='404' subStatusCode='-1' prefixLanguageFilePath='' path='/home/index' responseMode='ExecuteURL'/> 
</httpErrors>
```